# Proving linear independence of set and one unique vector

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am stuck on a problem in my practice sheet (not homework) and I had a question regarding this problem.

> Let V be a vector space, W a subspace of V , S a linearly independent subset of W , and v ∈ V \W.Prove that
> S ∪ {v} is linearly independent.

I wanted to know what is the meaning of the notation **V\W**? Does it have any effect on the way we solve the problem?
I think it means that *v* belongs to V but not W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot comment yet but I am just trying to help. Anyone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Since $S \subset W$ then Span$(S)$ is a subspace of $W$, and since it is given that $v \notin W$, then $v \notin$ Span$(S)$ and therefore no linear combination of $S$ could produce $v$ and so $S \ \cup \ \{v\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Use `\notin` to get $\notin$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

$V \setminus W$ is $V$ without $W$ and is sometimes written $V-W$. The latex command for this is \setminus for this reason. Formally if $v \in V \setminus W$ then $v \in V, v \notin W$.

Comment: Understood! Thanks a lot!